# What the difference between a Windows service and a Windows process?

Tags: windows, service, process

What is the **difference** between a Windows **service** and a Windows **process**?

Comment: A service is always a process (or maybe even more than one process), but a process does not necessarily run as a service.

Comment: You can have a look at this [post](http://superuser.com/questions/209654/whats-the-difference-between-an-application-process-and-services).

Comment: this sounds like more of a superuser question

Answer (score 38):

A service is a true-blooded Windows process, no difference there.  The only thing that's special about a service is that it is started by the operating system and runs in a separate session.  An isolated one that keeps it from interfering with the desktop session.  Traditionally named a [*daemon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29).

Comment: But isn't a process without UI considered a daemon too? Let's take Apache web server as an example, does running Apache as a windows service provide more "***running power***" than running Apache by calling `bin\httpd.exe` directly?

Comment: Sure, Apache doesn't quit running when the user logs out.

Comment: What about running it using `runas`, **vs** running it using windows service? Is there a difference in "running power", or are they actually different ways to do an **identical** thing?

Comment: That just changes the user account for the process, not the session that it runs in.  Click the Ask Question button to ask questions please.

Answer (score 1):

A service is a process **without** user interface. You can call service as a subset of process.

Answer (score 0):

Windows services are essentially long-running executable applications that run in their own windows sessions and do not possess any user interface. These can be automatically started when the computer boots up and can be paused and restarted.